# Android Vertical Nested RecyclerView not scrolling

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView`, and each `ViewHolder` has another `RecyclerView`. However only the parent `RecyclerView` gets focus and the child `RecyclerView` does not ever get any focus.

I need the child to get focus so it can scroll. Has anyone managed to do that?